# "NOT NEAR" matching in sphinxsearch?

Tags: full-text-search, sphinx

Say have an some strings like

```
sphinxQL> select * from rttest where match('beach');
+------+--------+---------------------------------------------+
| id   | weight | value                                       |
+------+--------+---------------------------------------------+
|   12 |   1576 | looking down on the beach from Beach Street |
|   10 |   1555 | This is a beach                             |
|   11 |   1555 | photo of Beach Street                       |
+------+--------+---------------------------------------------+
```

How can match documents that do contain "beach", but not when its just part of "Beach Street" phrase.

This sort of works:

```
sphinxQL> select * from rttest where match('beach -"beach street"');
+------+--------+-----------------+
| id   | weight | value           |
+------+--------+-----------------+
|   10 |   1527 | This is a beach |
+------+--------+-----------------+
```

But ideally we should get document 12 as well. As we have beach on its own too.

> looking down on the **beach** from Beach Street

Just excluding the phrase, excludes all documents with the phrase, regardless if they match just the single keyword too.

Something like 'NOT NEAR' would be ideal:

```
sphinxQL> select * from rttest where match('beach -NEAR/1 street');
ERROR 1064 (42000): index rttest: syntax error, unexpected TOK_NEAR near 'NEAR/1 street'
```

But as we don't have that, any other way to do it? (aside from post processing ;)

Comment: As it appears its not possible right now. Added as a feature request... http://sphinxsearch.com/bugs/view.php?id=1259

Answer (score 0):

Well in case anyone finds this, I've figured out a workaround. Posted on the sphinx forum:

http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=9869

But a quick summary

```
select *,weight() MOD 4 AS w from from rttest 
  where match('beach | "beach street" | "beach street" | "beach street" ') 
  and w > 0 order by w desc option ranker=wordcount;

+------+---------------------------------------------+------+
| id   | value                                       | w    |
+------+---------------------------------------------+------+
|   10 | This is a beach                             |    1 |
|   12 | looking down on the beach from Beach Street |    1 |
+------+---------------------------------------------+------+
```

This on includes documents with 'beach', any with **just** 'beach street' are **excluded**.

(because "beach street" matches all 4 terms, multiples of 4 are excluded. If there is a singluer beach - on its own, or **along with** the phrase, its no longer exactly 4 (eg its 1 or 5) and so still included. The result of the modulus operation should be how many single words there are)